# ASP.NET MVC Ajax helpers block other Ajax requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have this very strange problem.

Currently I'm using ASP.NET MVC Ajax Ajax.BeginForm helper.

After it creates successful post request to server and receives response my other components that use ajax, are not able to request anything from server (Firebug just does not display any requests, at the same in another browser window I can get response from server just fine the problem is defiantly not on server side).

But when I return nothing in response to Ajax.BeginForm helper request my other ajax components are able to make requests to server.

Is it a know issue with ASP.NET Ajax or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank You very much!

Comment: Could you please post some codes (include both the requests failed and succeed) here? so that we can indicate the issue more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably crashing the application server with that request. Check your server logs. If your debugging this kind of thing happens, your maybe not catching an exception.

Comment: That's was first thing I've looked, but everything is fine on server end. Thank You!